# Combine two variables/paths in bat script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to combine zip all the contents of a folder. Following is in my bat file:

```
set DESIGN="%1"
set new_var="%2"
powershell Compress-Archive -Path %DESIGN%\* -DestinationPath %DESIGN%\%new_var%.zip
```

Below is how I am calling it:

```
zip_power.bat C:\rehost res_h
```

Below is the cmd output:

[image: what I see]

It is adding additional quotes. How do I concatenate two paths?

Comment: `set "DESIGN=%~1"` is the best way, so the quotes do not become part of the value, and the `~`-modifier removes potential quotes from the argument. You should then quote the concatenated path in order to protect spaces and special characters…

Comment: **1.** `@Set "DESIGN=%~1"` **2.** `@Set "new_var=%~2"` **3.** `@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile "Compress-Archive -Path '%DESIGN%\*' -DestinationPath '%DESIGN%\%new_var%.zip'"`

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the " marks when you are setting the variables... so they are included when you inject them into the later statement.

try

```
set DESIGN=%1
```